# Ionic:download file on iCloud

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

i am building app in ionic framework and in that app i want to download feature for IOS but wan't be able to find proper solution.
basically i want to downlaod and save file on iCloud using $cordovaFileTransfer.download.
i try below targetDir

```
cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory;
```

but when i try to find on iCloud i wan't be able to find that file and also i am not getting any error while downloading file.
so there is no way to make sure whether that file getting stored or not.

Please can someone provide me the guideline to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: no still not found any solution for this

Comment: I am also facing an issue with the upload, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705909/ionic-3-ios-cant-read-data-from-file?noredirect=1#comment78380130_45705909

Would you mind taking a look please

Comment: Have you find solution for this? I'm also facing this problem